# Under some regularity assumptions to the boundary $\partial\Omega$, the first weak eigenfunction of $-\Delta$ in $\Omega$ is also a strong one

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, holder-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded domain, $H:=W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ be the [Sobolev space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_space), $C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega)$ be the [Hölder space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder_condition) for some $\alpha\in (0,1]$ and $\langle\;\cdot\;,\;\cdot\;\rangle_2$ be the $L^2(\Omega)$ scalar product. Let's consider the eigenvalue problem for $-\Delta$ in $\Omega$, i.e. $$-\Delta u=\lambda u\;.\tag{1}$$ Let $\Theta\in H$ and $\lambda_1>0$ be the first *weak* eigenfunction and eigenvalue, respectively, i.e. $(\Theta,\lambda_1)$ being a solution of $$\langle\nabla u,\nabla\varphi\rangle_2=\lambda\langle u,\varphi\rangle_2\;\;\;\text{for all }u\in H\tag{2}$$ such that there is no other solution $(u,\lambda)$ of $(2)$ with $\lambda<\lambda_1$.

---

Now, I've read that if the boundary $\partial\Omega$ is a $C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega)$-submanifold, then

1. $\Theta\in C^{2,\alpha}(\Omega)$
2. $\Theta>0$
3. $\Theta$ is a (strong) eigenfunction with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$, i.e. $(\Theta,\lambda_1)$ is a solution of $(1)$

How do I need to understand this? $\Theta$ is an equivalence class of functions. So, what's is meant (especially) by $(1.)$ and $(2.)$?

Comment: The only thing I could imagine is, that they mean, that there is some representative of $\Theta$ which satisfies $(1.)$, $(2.)$ and $(3.)$.

Comment: Yes, $\Theta$ is equal a.e. to a $C^{2,\alpha}$ function. That makes sense because it cannot be equal a.e. to two different $C^{2,\alpha}$ functions because two $C^{2,\alpha}$ functions that are equal a.e. are the same.

Comment: @TrialAndError That's the problem. Formally, $\Theta$ *cannot* be a.e. to a $C^{2,\;\alpha}$-function, since $\Theta$ is a *set*. So, shouldn't we state, that there is some Hölder continuous and positive representative of $\Theta$?

Comment: @TrialAndError I think, it's misleading to say, that a $f\in L^p$ is continuous, since we all know, that it's no problem to modify any representative of $f$ on a null set, such that this representative is not continuous while the original and modified one are a.e. equal.

Comment: It's part of the standard language of the subject, but it takes a bit to learn. If someone says that $f \in L^{p}$ is in $C^{2,\alpha}$, then they mean there exists $\tilde{f} \in C^{2,\alpha}$ such that $\tilde{f} \in f$. If there exists such $\tilde{f}$, then it is unique, i.e., meaning that there cannot be two different functions $C^{2,\alpha}$ in the equivalence class $f$. People also treat $f \in L^{p}$ as a function, even though, strictly speaking, it is an equivalence class; but the notation $[f]$ just becomes too cumbersome.

Comment: It is just fine to say that $f \in L^{p}$ is in $C^{2,\alpha}$ if you understand that it means there exists a continuous function $\tilde{f} \in C$ such that $\tilde{f} \in f$. This is because any two continuous functions on a domain $\Omega$ that are equal a.e. are equal. That's a good exercise to work through just once for yourself.

Comment: @0xbadf00d : Can you please let me know where you have read this. Also can you explain the condition on the boundary, in a bit lay man terms, without symbolic and not using the sub manifold jargon? I am precisely interested in knowing "when" a weak eigen function is also strong, for laplacian. Is it true for a square domain in $\mathbb{R}^N$.